# user not showing up as a value even after saving it in its prisma model in both user and session

Tags: typescript, mongodb, next.js, prisma

[Image of the session model being accessed in the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyLW0.png) I am trying to access the user from the session model in the mongodb using prisma but every other value except user is not showing up ( id: string;
sessionToken: string;
userId: string;
expires: Date;). I have saved the user in the model for session but it isnt showing up.

This is the schema.prsima file:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Product {
  id          String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  description String
  imageUrl    String
  name        String
  price       Int
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt
  CartItem    CartItem[]

  @@map("products")
}

model Cart {
  id        String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  items  CartItem[]
  userId String? @db.ObjectId
  user User? @relation(fields:[userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  @@map("carts")
}

model CartItem {
  id        String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  productId String @db.ObjectId
  product   Product @relation(fields:[productId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  quantity  Int
  cartId    String @db.ObjectId
  cart Cart @relation(fields:[cartId], references: [id], onDelete:Cascade)

  @@map("cartItems")
}


model Account {
  id                String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userId            String  @db.ObjectId
  type              String
  provider          String
  providerAccountId String
  refresh_token     String? @db.String
  access_token      String? @db.String
  expires_at        Int?
  token_type        String?
  scope             String?
  id_token          String? @db.String
  session_state     String?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
  @@map("accounts")
}

model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String   @db.ObjectId
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@map("sessions")
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
  Cart          Cart[]

  @@map("users")
}

model VerificationToken {
  id         String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  identifier String
  token      String   @unique
  expires    DateTime

  @@unique([identifier, token])
  @@map("verificationtokens")
}
```

This is where I am trying to access the user:

```
import { Session } from "@prisma/client"
import Image from "next/image";
import profilepicplaceholder from "../../assets/profile-pic-placeholder.png"
import { signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react";
interface UserMenuButtonProps {
    session : Session | null
} 


export default function UserMenuButton(session: UserMenuButtonProps) {
    const user = session?.user

    return(
        <div className="dropdown dropdown-end">
            <label tabIndex={0} className="btn btn-ghost btn-circle">
                {
                    user? 
                    <Image src={user?.image || profilepicplaceholder } alt="profile pic" width={40} height={40} className="w-10 rounded-full"/>:
                    <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    className="inline-block h-5 w-5 stroke-current"
                  >
                    <path
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                      strokeWidth="2"
                      d="M5 12h.01M12 12h.01M19 12h.01M6 12a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0zm7 0a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0zm7 0a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0z"
                    />
                  </svg>
                }
            </label>
            <ul tabIndex={0} className="dropdown-content menu rounded-box menu-sm z-3 mt-3 w-52 bg-base-100 p-2 shadow">
                <li>{user? <button onClick={()=> signOut({callbackUrl:"/"})}>Sign out</button> : <button onClick={()=> signIn()}>Sign In</button>}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is what its telling :
Property 'user' does not exist on type 'UserMenuButtonProps'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 0):

You should use destructuring of your properties:

```
UserMenuButton({ session }: UserMenuButtonProps)
```

The properties are passed in as the reference to the object, so either destruct it in the parameter, or rename **session** to **props** and then use `props.session.user`

Comment: thanks for pointing out that mistake but that doesnt fix it, the problem is that the user isnt showing as part of the session model at all. Check out the link to the image i just added it should explain it

Comment: Did you remember to regenerate the Prisma Client? https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-prismaclient/generating-prisma-client

Comment: Otherwise, it is likely to do with how Prisma handles relations for MongoDB. I have only used it with Postgres myself, but you can find more info here: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations#mongodb